# Javascript <input> doesn't work well with IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on my `Django` project and I'm getting an issue with `Javascript` part and `IE 11`.
My functions work well with `Firefox` and `Chrome` but not as I want with Internet Explorer 11.

**Process :**

I have a table with checkboxes, a dropdown list and a submitting button.
This button is disabled while I didn't have any checkboxes checked and any value selected in the dropdown list.

**Pictures :**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the submit button is disabled if :

- None checkboxes and list value are selected
- Checkboxes checked but not list value
- Checkboxes unchecked but list value selected

The submit button is enabled only if checkboxes and list value are selected.

**My code :**

**Javascript part :**

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    function checkValid() {
      var cbChecked = $(".fake-radio").is(":checked");  // check if checked

      var selectelem = document.getElementById('manage-doc-year');
      var btnelem = document.getElementById('document-button');
      btnelem.disabled = !selectelem.value;
      var dropdown_value = btnelem.disabled;

      $("#document-button").prop("disabled", !cbChecked || dropdown_value);
    }

    $(function () {
      checkValid(); // run it for the first time
      $(".fake-radio").on("change", checkValid);  // bind checkbox
      $("#manage-doc-year").on("input", checkValid)  // bind textbox
    });

</script>
```

**HTML part :**

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
  <h4> {% trans "List of documents:" %} </h4>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table id="document-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table_model">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{% trans 'Choice' %}</th>
        <th>{% trans 'Document title' %}</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for document in query_document %}
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="fake-radio" id="document-checkbox" name="DocumentChoice"
                     value="{{ document.id }}"></td>
          <td>{{ document.title }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <select id="manage-doc-year" name="q1year" value="{{ request.get.q1year }}" required>
      <option selected="selected">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
      </option>
    </select>

    <button class="btn btn-default" id="document-button" type="submit"
            name="UpdateDocument">{% trans "Submit" %}</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**IE 11 :**

With IE 11, it works only if I select dropdown value first, then check the checkboxes. But not if I check in first, then I select value. Why ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility) `input` event on `<select>` element.
Consider listening on `change` event if on IE.

You can write :

```
$("#manage-doc-year").on("change", checkValid)
```

Instead of :

```
$("#manage-doc-year").on("input", checkValid)
```

Note: Although `change` event is supported by all browsers, its behaviour is a bit different than `input` event's ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#See_also)):

> `change` fires less often than `input` – it only fires when the changes are committed by the user.

and may vary on different browsers ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change#Description)):

> Different browsers do not always agree whether a `change` event should be fired for certain types of interaction. For example, keyboard navigation in `<select>` elements never fires a change event in Gecko until the user hits Enter or switches the focus away from the `<select>`

Comment: If IE doesn't support `<select>` element, why it works if I select dropdown value first, then checkboxes ?

Comment: It doesn't support `input` event on that element, not element itself. When you select checkbox then `change` event on element with class `fake-radio` is fired

Comment: Ok, so I have to change `$("#manage-doc-year").on("input", checkValid)  // bind textbox` to this `$("#manage-doc-year").on("change", checkValid)  // bind textbox` ?

Comment: Yes, at least for IE

Comment: Ok, but I see it's compatible with all browsers. So maybe I can generalize this to all ? And don't make any condition : if IE or not ^^

Comment: It's supported by other browsers, but there are some differences in behaviour, see `change` event [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change#Description)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like changing the dropdown is not triggering your event. This is a known issue with Internet Explorer (I believe that if you use the keyboard to select a dropdown entry, it does work). I recommend you tie the event to click instead.

Comment: Maybe some code to propose ? I'm not sure you're right. Because if I select dropdown value first, then checkboxes it works. Not the inverse.